# No matching client found for package name 'com.example.myapp '

Tags: android, firebase

This is a part of my google-services.json:

```
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:870942488540:android:61cde8f21dabd0d2844119",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.firebase.uidemo"
        }
      },
```

and build output shows:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.firebase.uidemo'

how could I fix the problem? Hope someone could tell me, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

See your package name on your google-services.json file and inside the client change the package as com.example.myapp

Comment: @rahan why should it be changed? if it is already defined everywhere including firebase console, json file, build.gradle and manifest file. Moreover, package IDs like com.example.... are not supported by Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

1.Change the package_name in json file to com.example.myapp

Comment: why should it be changed? if it is already defined everywhere including firebase console, json file, build.gradle and manifest file. Moreover, package IDs like com.example.... are not supported by Play Store.